# What happens when you accidentally inhale smoke once?

Tags: smoking, asthma, smoke-inhalation, second-hand-smoke, asthma-attack

I usually wear a mask to cover my mouth and nose, because I am very sensitive to pungent smells. But one day I forgot to bring them when going out. I was walking to my flat one day, and was passing by a narrow path. There was a person going in the opposite direction who was smoking, and as I walked closer to him, I forgot to hold my breath and inhaled one of the most unpleasant, painful smell in a very long time. A few minutes later, I had a headache, momentary chest pain and an asthma attack (rarely happen), as I arrived at my flat. It lasted for several minutes.

I feel much better now, but should I be concerned with the accidental inhalation I’ve done, and what negative effects it will give me in the long-term? I am very sensitive to strong, unhealthy smells, and having just experienced an asthma attack, which rarely happens to me, I extremely fear for my well-being. Thank you in advance.

(I only made one large inhalation)